# How do I search for items that are expanded?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a treeview that can be updated by an asynchronous event, so when the event occurs and sends the new data to the treeview, it collapses. I would like to know if there is a possibility of updating it without doing a refresh of the whole component?

**EDIT**

Before update the data I´d like to know the itens that are expanded for after update the data keep the tree opened like before.

Comment: Do you have some kind of UID field on the tree nodes that is kept the same after the update? (not including node changes of course)

Comment: I tried to improve the question to better show my problem.

Comment: The question was clear before the edit :) Perhaps my comment wasn't clear so I'll explain: After the update, all the references to the data nodes are different so there's no way to track which nodes were expanded by reference. Using indexes is also out of the question since after the update the indexes can change. The only way, as I see it, is to store the UID (Unique Identification number) of the nodes that were expanded and then re-expand the nodes with the same UIDs after the update. Do you have a UID for each node on the tree?